# PHP Emails are sending, but headers are not

Tags: php, email, header

I'm using several different mailers for a single website, because right now, none of them are working correctly. And they're all malfunctioning in the exact same way, ,so I don't believe that it's any of the mail functions, but I'd like another set of eyes on this to make sure I'm not missing something.

Here's what's happening:

The emails send just fine, but it looks like none of the header info I set is being used. When you get an email, the html is displaying as code, and the subject shows as part of the message.

Here's the header info:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;
$headers .= "To: $nameto <$to>" . $newLine;
$headers .= "From: $namefrom <$from>" . $newLine
```

Here's the Send:

```
if ($test == true) {
    mail($to, $from, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    echo "<script>window.location = '/key-holders/index.php';</script>";
}
```

And here is what the email looks like:

```
<html><body><center><table bgcolor='#ededed' width='680px'><tr><td><img src='http://example.com/img/logo.png'  /></td></tr><tr><td><p>User Name has left you a special message on The Website.<br /> Please go to <a href='http://example.com/message/5493536206ab2'>http://example.com/message/5493536206ab2</a> to view your message.</p></td></tr></table></center></body></html>
    User Name Has a Special Message For You
```

Edit - Here's $newLine:

```
    $newLine = "\r\n";
```

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php *best thing*. You'll also need to show us what's in `$newLine`. That could be a contributing factor; broken headers.

Comment: Btw, headers only has 4 parameters, you have 5 `$to, $from, $subject, $message, $headers`. There's (part) of the problem if not **thee** problem. Again, read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - At best, remove the `$from`. That could very well fix it. `From:` is already in your headers `"From: $namefrom <$from>"`

Comment: Please, stop using raw `mail` and use a class like SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: All the work in comments; *bummer.*

Comment: You're also missing a semi-colon for `$headers .= "From: $namefrom <$from>" . $newLine` unless that's a bad copy/paste. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. That will help you debug your code.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bad copy/paste. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm thinking it's the `\r\n` not being properly concatenated. Just to test, remove that variable from all the headers and use `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"  . "\r\n";` in its place. I'm next to certain it will work. Do the same for the other headers. As it stands, they could be interpreted as `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"  . \r\n;` with no quotes, instead of the intended `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"  . "\r\n";` with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$from` parameter from [mail function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php):

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Make sure, that `$newLine = "\r\n";`

Comment: @larryoscs Take a look into the raw code of your email after receiving it. Does it contain the correct headers?